# Api to get total transfer count of an ERC-721 Token

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, tokens, etherscan, erc-721

I want to retrieve the total number of an erc 721 token's transfers/ transactions. I couldn't scrape the transfers value from etherscan as well e.g. given here https://etherscan.io/token/0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d. Is there any api by which I can just get the total amount of transcations/transfers of an ERC-721 token?

Comment: I think you'll have to scan through the entire chain for specific events/transactions that have for topic said token.

Comment: Voting down because you didn't show us what you tried.

Comment: I tried scraping the Etherscan block explorer as stated above. But the limit from that comes in the form of sometimes only the latest 500k transfers being shown. And let's suppose if a Transfer event wasn't fired upon token transfer, then what other way is left to carry out this task as manually traversing each and every transaction would be very cumbersome.

Comment: There is also an "ERC20 - Token Transfer Events" by Address api http://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokentx&address=0x4e83362442b8d1bec281594cea3050c8eb01311c&startblock=0&endblock=999999999&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken provided by etherscan but couldn't find any such api provided for erc721 tokens.